# Выводит не по порядку. Как исправить? C++

Tags: c++

```
int x, s=0;
cout<<"Input a binary number: ";
cin>>x;
cout<<x<<"=";
while(x != 0){
    s = x % 1000;
    if(s==000)cout<<"Zero";
    if(s==001)cout<<"One";
    if(s==010)cout<<"Two";
    if(s==011)cout<<"Three";
    if(s==100)cout<<"Four";
    if(s==101)cout<<"Five";
    if(s==110)cout<<"Six";
    if(s==111)cout<<"Seven";

    x = x / 1000;
}
```

Я ввожу 111001, по сути должно вывести *SevenOne*, а выводит *OneSeven*, то есть в обратном порядке.

Почему, как исправить?

Comment: Хе! Как вы думаете, чему равно число `010`? Если назвать его словами? ([_Подсказка._](http://ideone.com/YUfo58))

Comment: И затем, к сути. Как вы думаете, что делает операция `x % 1000`? Оно выбирает у числа старшие или младшие три цифры?

Comment: скорее всего старшие. тогда как выбать младшие три цифры числа?

Comment: Пора осваивать отладчик...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вы не можете ввести двоичное число.

Данное число, 111001, которое вы вводите через консоль, это десятичное число.

Остаток от деления на 1000

```
s = x % 1000;
```

даст вам  1. Поэтому все правильно, что сначала выводится на консоль слово

```
One
```

После предложения

```
x = x / 1000;
```

Переменная `x` имеет значение 111.

Остаток от деления на 1000 этого вновь полученного числа в предложении

```
s = x % 1000;
```

будет равен самому числу, то есть 111.

Это число, сравниваемое в предложении

```
if(s==111)cout<<"Seven";
```

даст в качестве результата `true`, и на консоль будет выведено

```
Seven
```

Име1те в виду, что все числовые литералы в этих if предложениях

```
if(s==000)cout<<"Zero";
if(s==001)cout<<"One";
if(s==010)cout<<"Two";
if(s==011)cout<<"Three";
```

являются представлениями чисел в восьмиричной системе, так как они начинаются с 0.

То есть, фактически, вы имеете

```
if ( s == 0 ) cout<<"Zero";
if ( s == 1 ) cout<<"One";
if ( s == 8 ) cout<<"Two";
if ( s == 9 ) cout<<"Three";
```

В С++ вы можете указывать двоичные литералы. Например, вы могнли бы написать

```
if ( s == 0b000 ) cout<<"Zero";
if ( s == 0b001 ) cout<<"One";
if ( s == 0b010 ) cout<<"Two";
if ( s == 0b011 )cout<<"Three";
```

Но проблема состоит в том, что нельзя через консоль ввести число в двоичном представление как целочисленное значение.

Вам придется вводить его как строку и преобразовывать в двоичное число.

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает подход к решению вашей задачи.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "111" );

    int x = std::stoi( s, nullptr, 2 );

    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет равен

```
7
```

что действительно соответствует двоичному представлению числа в виде `0b111`

Я думаю, что вы хотели получить что-то вроде такого

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "111001" );

    int x = std::stoi( s, nullptr, 2 );

    while ( x != 0 )
    {
        int s = x % 0b1000;

        if ( s == 0b000 ) std::cout << "Zero ";
        if ( s == 0b001 ) std::cout << "One ";
        if ( s == 0b010 ) std::cout << "Two ";
        if ( s == 0b011 ) std::cout << "Three ";
        if ( s == 0b100 ) std::cout << "Four ";
        if ( s == 0b101 ) std::cout << "Five ";
        if ( s == 0b110 ) std::cout << "Six ";
        if ( s == 0b111 ) std::cout << "Seven ";

        x = x / 0b1000;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль

```
One Seven
```

Но учтите, что ваш компилятор должен поддерживать двоичные литералы. Иначе вам придется их записать либо в шестнадцатиричном или восьмиричном виде.

Answer (score 1):

Можно запомнить вычисленные слова в цикле, а вывести их в обратном порядке в другом цикле:

```
std::stack<std::string> numbers;
while (x != 0){
   s = x % 1000;

   if (s == 000) numbers.push("Zero");
   ...
   if (s == 111) numbers.push("Seven");

   x = x / 1000;
}

while (!numbers.empty()) {
  std::cout << numbers.top()
  numbers.pop();
}
```

Оффтоп 1: cкорее всего у вас в программе есть ошибка. Целочисленные литералы начинающиеся с '0' интерпретируются как числа в восьмеричной системе. Т.е. 011 на самом деле равно 9.

Оффтоп 2: в данном случае я бы посоветовал представлять введенные бинарные числа в виде строк.